# How to select a value from Auto suggestions using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

1. Go to google.com
2. Type a search keyword
3. I want to select 3rd/4th value from the auto suggestions list. What method should I use in selenium python ?

Comment: There are three separate questions here: 
"How do I navigate to a static uri?"
"How do I select a text box and type in the field?"
and "How do I click on an option?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google search page contains a `<div class="gstl_0 sbdd_a">`

When you start typing into the search box, that div becomes populated with an `<ul role="listbox">`. The `<li>` in that list contain the 4 suggestions. Pick one, and call the .click() method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python, but i do have code in C# which i was able to succeed. You can give it  try.

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

IWebElement txtboxSearch = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
txtboxSearch.SendKeys("ap");

IList<IWebElement> autosaerchList = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".sbsb_c.gsfs"));
autosaerchList[1].Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('Path to chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('Shah') #pass whatever you want to search
time.sleep(5)

# to click on third element of search suggestion
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]').click()

# to click on fourth element of search suggestion, uncomment the next line and comment the previous one
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[4]/div/div[2]').click()
```

Hope this help